# Can sql query result be manually mapped with room?

Tags: android-room

Lets say in my dao class i have a method annotated with sql: `SELECT id, name, lat, long FROM table WHERE id = :id`.

i want to map that to object like (pseudo):

```
public class Something {
  public string Id;
  public string Name;
  public GeoLocation Location;

  public Something(id, name, lat, long) {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Location = new GeoLocation(lat, long);
  }
}
```

so, point is that i want to map flat select result into model with children made from some of the return fields.

Important is that i don’t want to have public get/set for all fields that sql returns.

I also want to avoid any room annotations on `Something` if possible (i am aware of solutions that involve `@Embedded` annotations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In room the only possible way to convert fields into POJO that has no boiler point is indeed `@Embedded` annotation. Thats the best and simplest way to do it.

You can convert your sql query to your desired model with some other few methods which are not feasible.

1. Intermediate Model. That is convert your SQL result to a model that one to one matches to your fields. i.e.

```
public class PreSomething {
  public string id;
  public string name;
  public long lat;
  public long long;
}
```

After converting to `PreSomething`, you can have it get converted `Something` with any fashion you like.

2. Another way would be `TypeConverters` which changes database schema and will require you have database migration.

So, the only possible way is infact `@Embedded`. Now coming to your requirements,

> Important is that i don’t want to have public get/set for all fields
>   that sql returns.

Every field that's stored in the database needs to be either public or have a "getter" method. Since your fields are all public you don't have to have any get/set for the fields.

> I also want to avoid any room annotations on Something if possible (i
>   am aware of solutions that involve @Embedded annotations).

You have to annotate `@Embedded` the `GeoLocation` object (not `Something`) in order to be able to map your fields to a POJO.

One other thing to note that you `SQLite`, in that fashion Room, is case sensitive so. If you have to specify your fields with lowercase if your columns are lowercase. Otherwise you have to annotate them with `@ColumnInfo` and correct column name.

Comment: yes, thats what i was afraid of; that it might be a bit more complex and/or impossible without annotations. thank you very much for a nice explanation!